# Android Как отменить перезагрузку webView после того как пользователь свернул приложение

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Как отменить перезагрузку webView после того как пользователь свернул приложение и вернулся в **Android**?
MainActivity.java

```
package app.beer.crazycahs;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;
private static String URL = "http://crazycash.tv";
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    init();
}

private void init() {
    hideUserBars();

    sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);

    // add clients for webView
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    webView.setNetworkAvailable(true);

    // enable javascript and otros functions
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setFocusable(true);
    webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_INSET);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ConstraintLayout noInternetLabel = findViewById(R.id.not_internet);
    if (hasConnection()) {
        noInternetLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // load web site
        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String urlFromShared = sharedPreferences.getString("page_url", URL);
        if (urlFromShared != null) {
            if (urlFromShared.equals(URL)) {
                webView.loadUrl(URL);
            } else {
                webView.loadUrl(urlFromShared);
            }
        }
    } else {
        webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        noInternetLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

private void hideUserBars() {
    // скрываем user бары
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

public boolean hasConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo wifiInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (wifiInfo != null && wifiInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    wifiInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if (wifiInfo != null && wifiInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    wifiInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return wifiInfo != null && wifiInfo.isConnected();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("page_url", webView.getUrl());
    editor.apply();
}

private static class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @SuppressLint("deprecated")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: А точно SharedPreferences так работает? А где getSharedPreferences(settings, MODE_PRIVATE);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

НУ у вас в onResume() есть код который вызывает перезагрузку вашей WebView

```
if (urlFromShared != null) {
            if (urlFromShared.equals(URL)) {
                webView.loadUrl(URL);
            } else {
                webView.loadUrl(urlFromShared);
            }
        }
```

`onResume()` - вызывается всякий раз когда активити открывается на первом плане, а значит после каждого сворачивания. Перенесите эту логику в `onCreate()` и обновление будет происходить только при создании Активити

Вам стоит лучше ознакомиться с [Жизненным циклом Активити](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Comment: Он вообще-то, сначала urlFromShared из sharedPreferences читает и сравнивает значение с дефолтным. Так что не тут собака порылась.

Comment: Как оказалось собака зарыта именно там))